# The name attribute is invalid according to its datatype?

Tags: c#

I'm getting the error on the 2nd line starting from "themepark.ser..." However the same name is working fine in line 4, so I'm not sure whats going wrong here, also if I have tor rename anything, please direct how exactly to do so as I have unable to do so thus far following other solutions.

```
<services>
          <service name="themepark.Service1">
            <clear />
            <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="themepark.IService1" />
          </service>
        </services>
```

Comment: A name cannot contain a dot, but a contract is a compound name. The parts of the contract (namespace and interface) are separated by a dot.

Comment: I modified the code from an example,  in the example it works fine, I just changed the naming conventions suitable for my project